# Client Socket - Keep Socket Open Indefinitely

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am working on my first Java/Android sockets app that will act as a send/receive socket client. I have an existing app (server) that communicates using xml via sockets. This server can send out information to connected clients at any time so I must keep the socket open indefinitely once it has been created. The code below seems to be partially correct as I can send and receive direct responses however, I am unable to receive unsolicited messages?

```
public void Connect(String ip, int port)
{
    try
    {
        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
        Socket socket = new Socket(inetAddress, port);
        mConnected = true;

        try
        {
            mOutputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int bytesRead;
            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

            new Thread(new NetworkConnectHandler()).start();

            while (socket.isConnected())
            {
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
                {
                    mReceivedPacket = null;
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    mReceivedPacket = byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");


                    if (mReceivedPacket.indexOf(STX) > -1 && mReceivedPacket.indexOf(ETX) > -1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                byteArrayOutputStream.reset();

                if (mReceivedPacket != null)
                {
                    IncomingPacketHandler(XmlFromString(CleanIncomingPacket(mReceivedPacket)));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("Network Connect", "S: Error", ex);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("Network Connect", "C: Error", ex);
    }
}

public class NetworkConnectHandler implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ConnectHandler();
    }
}

protected void ConnectHandler()
{
    Log.e("ConnectHandler", "Connected");
    SendDoc(CreateIDPacket());
}
```

SendDoc sends an initial message to the server on the same socket that is created  in the Connect method. All sent messages will receive a response from the server. In this case, the message is sent and the response is received.

Comment: Define 'unable'. What happens instead? This code will receive anything that is sent. BTW Unless your messages are pure text you need an escape convention for embedded STX and ETX.

Comment: Thanks for the response. From the server application, I can see that message(s) have been sent to me however, they never come in on the socket. If I send a message to the server, it is received and I do receive its response. It seems that if the server sends out a message that I did not initiate, I do not receive it. Sending messages to the server even after not receiving the unsolicited ones go through without a problem as well and I am not resetting the socket? The way this socket is setup, it should always be listening... correct?

Comment: You are not showing that you send something to the server. What is the thread with the new NetworkConnectHandler doing?

Comment: Are you sending your messages wrapped in STX/ETX? This code will ignore anything that isn't.

Comment: @EJP - yes, all of the messages are wrapped in STX/ETX. My earlier tests were made against a remote server. I have since moved a copy of the same server application to my local machine. All tests run against the server on my local machine using the Android emulator work as expected without any messages lost. Are there any other permissions that need to be set in the Android Manifest other than android.permission.INTERNET? For the record, I have similar clients written in both C# and VB.NET that work just fine from the same local machine. Any thoughts?

Comment: @greenapps - The NetworkConnectHandler is sending out some initial messages to the server upon connection of the socket. This function is operating as it should.

Comment: "Sending messages to the server even after not receiving the unsolicited ones" Where are you doing that? If you don't show that code how can we help you?

Comment: Sending messages is not the issue and as I stated in my previous comment, I have since determined that everything works perfectly when I run all apps on the same local machine. Is there something that I am missing that is specific to the Android platform?

Comment: You could start answering all questions an realise that you have to show more code and tell more about the used protocol.

Comment: @greenapps - Please see the additional methods that I posted.

Comment: There is not much to see in your additional code. Please tell what the server sends. How many bytes about? Where are STX en ETX in this bytestream exactly? Where do you check in the client that the message is received correctly? Please indicate that in your code.

Comment: The problem that I am having lies prior to any checking of the packets after receival. I can manually force the server to send a message that I should receive. Looking at the above Connect() method, if I put a breakpoint within the second while loop, on the line with mReceivedPacket = null; nothing ever gets to this point, yet, the server says that it was sent.

Comment: Just an FYI, I took the same network classes that I am trying to use in the Android app and copied them over to a Java app in Netbeans and everything works perfectly... Why are some packets not being received on the Android platform??